# Deleting and transferring files remotely on OpenELEC

Tags: openelec, data-transfer, file-sharing

I run OpenELEC v4.2.1 on a RPi Model B. I download movies to an attached hard drive. Frequently I want to move these completed videos to a second usb drive also attached to the pi, but using my laptop on the same network as I can see the files. However when I try to copy and past I get a permission denied error.

What do I need to change to enable me to move a file from my hard drive to my usb drive?

Comment: You need to add some details here.  The other usb drive is attached to your laptop and you want to move files there from the one attached to the pi?  How are you viewing the files from the laptop (NFS, sshfs, etc.)?  Finally, if the issue is permission denied on the drive attached to the laptop, what does this have to do with the pi?

Comment: @goldilocks Apologies for being unclear. Both the hard drive and the usb stick are connected to a usb hub connected to the RPi. I type the IP address of the RPi into Windows Explorer and view the files from there. I think the permissions of the usb stick or hard drive may need to be altered.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to change to enable me to move a file from my hard drive to my usb drive?

GNU/Linux, of which openELEC is a form, attaches external storage as subdirectories of the root filesystem -- usually in `/mnt`, although they can go anywhere.

I'm actually not a openELEC user so I cannot provide you with specifics, but if you browse through the `/mnt` directory while the drives are attached you should be able to figure that part out.  The next aspect has to do with *[permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)*; as a particular user you may be allowed to view a directory but not write things to it.

If you know where the second drive is mounted and you are just using this on a home LAN (i.e., don't have to get too paranoid), you can make the directory world writable with:

```
chmod a+w /mnt/foobar
```

Where `/mnt/foobar` is the subdirectory.  This won't persist across reboots though.